# TinyTex Failing to Compile RMarkdown Document

Tags: r, tinytex

I am attempting to create a CV and resume in RMarkdown using the "vitae" package (https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae/tree/master), but my RStudio has been returning the below error message:

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Master_Resume.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Master_Resume.log for more info.
Execution halted

The error seems to only occur on a new computer I purchased, despite successfully installing RStudio on it and being able to install all packages successfully by following the article at https://robertochiosa.medium.com/import-export-r-packages-a6a122005e00. I am still able to complile/knit the RMarkdown file to a pdf successfully on my old computer, just not my new one.

Per the suggestion in the error message, I followed the troubleshooting steps at https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging. See the steps below and what happened after each step:

STEP ONE: Update all  R and LaTeX packages.

I was successfully able to ensure all R and LaTeX packages are up-to-date,

STEP TWO: Reinstall TinyTex.

I was able to reinstall TinyTex successfully.

STEP THREE: If neither updating nor reinstalling solves the problem, set the option in R to show additional messages to help me debug the problem:

```
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

This resulted in the message: "I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log Master_Resume.log.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Master_Resume.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Master_Resume.log for more info.
Execution halted"

Comment: which os do you use? maybe try https://miktex.org/download  ot similar and check if its path is in PATH?

Comment: Hi @Ferroao. Thank you for your suggestion. I attempted to download the latest version of Miktex and ensured that its path is correctly listed in PATH. However, this still didn't seem to work. My OS is Windows 11. Open to any other suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: check Master_Resume.tex, it might require a line in the yaml header to preserve it. what about pandoc? do rstudio provides it? check if it is in PATH in rstudio termjnal.